# recurrence integral error

Tags: calculus

I am having problems with 3a). I basically managed to prove the required expression (recursive formula) except for the nasty little "n" coefficient term. Please see working out below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why you get an extra $n$? The first term, with $e$ substituted, should be $\ln(e)^n e^2/2 = 1^n e^2/2 = e^2/2$, as desired.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a case of bad handwriting.  Notice that you started writing with $u = (\ln x)^n$ with parentheses but then later on, you wrote $\ln x^n$ without the parentheses, which caused you to evaluate the integral incorrectly.  If you put the parentheses back in, then you'll get the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

$$I_n=\int_{1}^{e}x(\ln x)^ndx=\frac{x^2}{2}(\ln x)^n|_{1}^{e} -\int_{1}^{e}\frac{x^2}{2}(n(\ln x)^{n-1}\frac1x)dx\\I_n=\frac{e^2}{2}-\frac{n}{2}\int_{1}^{e}x^2((\ln x)^{n-1}\frac 1x)dx$$  can you take over?